# crm status failing to work after adding remote node

Tags: 14.04, juju, maas, canonical

My setup:

```
1. Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
2. Kilo Release (2015.1.3)
3. pacemaker: 1.1.10+git20130802-1ubuntu2.3
4. pacemaker-cli-utils: 1.1.10+git20130802-1ubuntu2.3
5. corosync: 2.3.3-1ubuntu2
6. libcorosync-common4: 2.3.3-1ubuntu2
7. resource agents: 1:3.9.3+git20121009-3ubuntu2
8. pacemaker-remote: 1.1.10+git20130802-1ubuntu2.3
9. fence-agents: 3.1.5-2ubuntu4
```

Here is the problem:

```
1. crm status command works
2. Add remote node
3. crm status command fails
```

Detailed view:

1. output of crm status:

   ```
   Last updated: Mon Apr 11 09:29:19 2016
   Last change: Mon Apr 11 09:17:35 2016 via cibadmin on juju-machine-2-lxc-20
   Stack: corosync
   Current DC: juju-machine-2-lxc-20 (1006) - partition with quorum
   Version: 1.1.10-42f2063
   3 Nodes configured
   8 Resources configured

   Online: [ juju-machine-1-lxc-20 juju-machine-2-lxc-20 juju-machine-8-lxc-20 ]

   Clone Set: cl_ping [ping]
   Started: [ juju-machine-1-lxc-20 juju-machine-2-lxc-20 juju-machine-8-lxc-20 ]
   res_nova_consoleauth (ocf::openstack:nova-consoleauth): Started juju-machine-8-lxc-20
   Resource Group: grp_nova_vips
   res_nova_eth0_vip (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2): Started juju-machine-8-lxc-20
   Clone Set: cl_nova_haproxy [res_nova_haproxy]
   Started: [ juju-machine-1-lxc-20 juju-machine-2-lxc-20 juju-machine-8-lxc-20 ]
   ```
2. Adding a remote node via crm:

   ```
   crm configure primitive compute0-B3 ocf:pacemaker:remote op monitor interval=20
   ```
3. Output of crm status command:

   ```
   Segmentation fault (core dumped) 
   ERROR: crm_mon exited with code 139 and said:
   ```
4. output of crm_mon command:

   ```
   Last updated: Mon Apr 11 10:54:59 2016
   Last change: Mon Apr 11 10:32:05 2016 via cibadmin on juju-machine-2-lxc-20
   Stack: corosync
   Current DC: juju-machine-2-lxc-20 (1006) - partition with quorum
   Version: 1.1.10-42f2063
   6 Nodes configured
   17 Resources configured

   Segmentation fault (core dumped)
   ```

the Version of pacemaker available upstream is 1.1.10. any latest pacemaker packages 1.1.13 or 1.1.14 upstream ?